# Symbolic solution to a nonlinear ordinary differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, symbolic-computation

Suppose $y=y(x)$ is infinite continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, and $y(-1)=0$, how can we obtain the analytic solution in closed form to the following nonlinear ordinary differential equation:

$$
\left((x-10)^2+y^2\right)\left(x^2+y^2y'^2+2xyy'+2yy'+2x+1\right)=\left(x^2+y^2\right)\left(x^2+y^2y'^2+2 x y y'-20y y'-20x+100\right)
$$

The resulted solution should be in implicit form. 
Is there any general approach in solving such kind of ODE's?

**Update:**

What I am asking is actually: is it possible to establish ellipse equation from only one of its properties as shown in the figure below. The light rays from one fixed point $F_1$ being reflected by the curve always focus on another fixed point $F_2$ and vice versa.

Suppose we don't know the curve is ellipse, then is it possible for us to obtain ellipse formulation only from the above relationship when being given $F_1$, $F_2$ and a point $A$ or $B$ on the curve?

I think the key now becomes how to establish the nonlinear ordinary equations or nonlinear systems to solve in polarized coordinate frame or just Descartes' frame. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular motivation for this system? I note that the second terms of each side factor as perfect squares. (Which leads to me wishing that the first term on the RHS was $((x+1)^2+y^2)$ instead, but I imagine that's not the case.)

Comment: I was trying to solve the ellipse curve's function given its two foci; Only through ODE solving, even after converting into polarized coordinate frame, it is still too difficult.

Comment: You might want to include that explicitly, then. Note that in that case a very good change of variables is to make the midpoint of the two foci the origin.

Comment: I am wondering whether there is any method in solving `differential equations` or just nonlinear equations that can lead to such a ellipse curve function. If it is explicitly known  as ellipse then with its properties as prerequisites the problem becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have obtained the nonlinear ODE with the analytic solution, which can be seen here: [ODE and IBCs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916768/how-to-solve-such-a-nonlinear-ode-the-analytical-solution-of-which-is-known)

Though it seems there is no classic approach available to solve such an ODE, the geometric meaning here can be seen as another solving approach to such nonlinear ODE problems.

**Update** A solution in details has been given in the same link: [ODE and IBCs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916768/how-to-solve-such-a-nonlinear-ode-the-analytical-solution-of-which-is-known)